# Serverless with localstack-serverless plugin not querying template locally

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless, localstack

Based on the official example on GitHub demonstrating a [serverless REST API](https://github.com/serverless/examples/tree/master/aws-python-rest-api-with-dynamodb) I enabled the `localstack-serverless` plugin so I could develop my services locally. I adjusted the `serverless.yml` file accordingly:

```
service: serverless-rest-api-with-dynamodb

frameworkVersion: ">=1.1.0 <2.0.0"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python2.7
  deploymentBucket:
    name: ${self:service}-${opt:stage}-deployment-bucket
  environment:
    DYNAMODB_TABLE: ${self:service}-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
      Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:${opt:region, self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:provider.environment.DYNAMODB_TABLE}"

custom:
  localstack:
    stages:
    - local
    - dev
    endpoints:
      S3: http://localhost:4572
      DynamoDB: http://localhost:4570
      CloudFormation: http://localhost:4581
      Elasticsearch: http://localhost:4571
      ES: http://localhost:4578
      SNS: http://localhost:4575
      SQS: http://localhost:4576
      Lambda: http://localhost:4574
      Kinesis: http://localhost:4568

plugins:
  - serverless-localstack

functions:
  create:
    handler: todos/create.create
    events:
      - http:
          path: todos
          method: post
          cors: true

  list:
    handler: todos/list.list
    events:
      - http:
          path: todos
          method: get
          cors: true

  get:
    handler: todos/get.get
    events:
      - http:
          path: todos/{id}
          method: get
          cors: true

  update:
    handler: todos/update.update
    events:
      - http:
          path: todos/{id}
          method: put
          cors: true

  delete:
    handler: todos/delete.delete
    events:
      - http:
          path: todos/{id}
          method: delete
          cors: true

resources:
  Resources:
    TodosDynamoDbTable:
      Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          -
            AttributeName: id
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          -
            AttributeName: id
            KeyType: HASH
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        TableName: ${self:provider.environment.DYNAMODB_TABLE}
```

Deploying on localstack running over docker:

```
SLS_DEBUG=3 serverless deploy --stage local --region us-east-1
```

it fails with the following message on the localstack side:

```
localstack_1  | 2019-12-04 10:41:33,692:API: 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Dec/2019 10:41:33] "PUT /serverless-rest-api-with-dynamodb-local-deployment-bucket HTTP/1.1" 200 -
localstack_1  | 2019-12-04 10:41:41,402:API: 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Dec/2019 10:41:41] "GET /serverless-rest-api-with-dynamodb-local-deployment-bucket?location HTTP/1.1" 200 -
localstack_1  | 2019-12-04 10:41:41,470:API: 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Dec/2019 10:41:41] "GET /serverless-rest-api-with-dynamodb-local-deployment-bucket?list-type=2&prefix=serverless%2Fserverless-rest-api-with-dynamodb%2Flocal HTTP/1.1" 200 -
localstack_1  | 2019-12-04 10:41:41,544:API: 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Dec/2019 10:41:41] "PUT /serverless-rest-api-with-dynamodb-local-deployment-bucket/serverless/serverless-rest-api-with-dynamodb/local/1575456101319-2019-12-04T10%3A41%3A41.319Z/compiled-cloudformation-template.json HTTP/1.1" 200 -
localstack_1  | 2019-12-04 10:41:41,569:API: 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Dec/2019 10:41:41] "PUT /serverless-rest-api-with-dynamodb-local-deployment-bucket/serverless/serverless-rest-api-with-dynamodb/local/1575456101319-2019-12-04T10%3A41%3A41.319Z/serverless-rest-api-with-dynamodb.zip HTTP/1.1" 200 -
localstack_1  | 2019-12-04T10:41:41:DEBUG:localstack.services.cloudformation.cloudformation_listener: Error response from CloudFormation (400) POST /: b'<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://cloudformation.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-05-15/">\n  <Error>\n    <Type>Sender</Type>\n    <Code>ValidationError</Code>\n    <Message>Stack with id serverless-rest-api-with-dynamodb-local does not exist</Message>\n  </Error>\n  <RequestId>cf4c737e-5ae2-11e4-a7c9-ad44eEXAMPLE</RequestId>\n</ErrorResponse>'
localstack_1  | 2019-12-04T10:41:41:WARNING:localstack.services.awslambda.lambda_api: Function not found: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:000000000000:function:serverless-rest-api-with-dynamodb-local-list
localstack_1  | 2019-12-04T10:41:41:WARNING:localstack.services.awslambda.lambda_api: Function not found: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:000000000000:function:serverless-rest-api-with-dynamodb-local-create
localstack_1  | 2019-12-04T10:41:41:WARNING:localstack.services.awslambda.lambda_api: Function not found: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:000000000000:function:serverless-rest-api-with-dynamodb-local-update
localstack_1  | 2019-12-04T10:41:41:WARNING:localstack.services.awslambda.lambda_api: Function not found: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:000000000000:function:serverless-rest-api-with-dynamodb-local-get
localstack_1  | 2019-12-04T10:41:41:WARNING:localstack.services.awslambda.lambda_api: Function not found: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:000000000000:function:serverless-rest-api-with-dynamodb-local-delete
localstack_1  | 2019-12-04T10:41:42:ERROR:localstack.services.generic_proxy: Error forwarding request: Unable to fetch template body (code 404) from URL https://s3.amazonaws.com/serverless-rest-api-with-dynamodb-local-deployment-bucket/serverless/serverless-rest-api-with-dynamodb/local/1575456101319-2019-12-04T10:41:41.319Z/compiled-cloudformation-template.json Traceback (most recent call last):
localstack_1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/generic_proxy.py", line 240, in forward
localstack_1  |     path=path, data=data, headers=forward_headers)
localstack_1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/cloudformation/cloudformation_listener.py", line 151, in forward_request
localstack_1  |     modified_request = transform_template(req_data)
localstack_1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/cloudformation/cloudformation_listener.py", line 70, in transform_template
localstack_1  |     template_body = get_template_body(req_data)
localstack_1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/cloudformation/cloudformation_listener.py", line 105, in get_template_body
localstack_1  |     raise Exception('Unable to fetch template body (code %s) from URL %s' % (response.status_code, url[0]))
localstack_1  | Exception: Unable to fetch template body (code 404) from URL https://s3.amazonaws.com/serverless-rest-api-with-dynamodb-local-deployment-bucket/serverless/serverless-rest-api-with-dynamodb/local/1575456101319-2019-12-04T10:41:41.319Z/compiled-cloudformation-template.json
```

Where we can see that the serverless deployment is trying to reach Amazon S3 directly, while I would expect it to use the local endpoint defined in the `serverless.yml` config (`http://localhost:4572`).

Is there a missing entry in the `serverless.yml` config file in order to force using the localstack S3 storage ?

Comment: Hmm that's odd, try taking out region?

Comment: Oh also checkout the readme and search for MountCode it looks like localstack will deploy lambda to s3 then download it without MountCode: true

Comment: Serverless complaining it is not finding the S3 bucket if I take out the region ... As for mountCode custom property: does not seem to play a role as I get the same error whether I set it to True or not.

Comment: Hrmm...interesting...let me grab it and I'll have a go. I mostly use sls offline with DDB local in docker.

Comment: Found it ... not related to serverless but to the localstack docker image I was using. localstack/localstack:0.10.4 is working.

Answer (score 1):

There is a regression with the localstack image I was using. Using the docker image `localstack/localstack:0.10.5` the deployment is successful.

Explicitely setting the region both in the config files AND the code also helps.